# What does this scipy curve_fit behavior mean?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` to fit a function to millions of data sets. I noticed that in my case there are three possible outcomes:

Either it fits fine and I get valid entries in `popt` and `pcov`, which happens in most cases.

Or, the fit seems fine, `popt` values look ok, but `pcov` is only filled with `inf`. What is the reason for that, what does it mean? In this case I cannot use the fitted values to plot the fitted curve, it just won't show in the plot without any error message.

And third, the code breaks with the error that `maxfev=600` was reached. In that case, how can I cause the program to run through anyway while still noticing those data sets to deal with them later?

Comment: You should read the documentation for this and take to cross-validated instead (the statistics stackexchange) because this is really a statistics question.  Your issue is that the covariance matrix of your parameters is filled with infinities.

Comment: Actually, the third question seems valid for SO, but requires more details

Comment: [Can you share your code incl. some test data?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Maybe you also see some warnings in the terminal during runtime. Can you share those, if any?

Comment: @frihax: for the `maxfev` question, you can manually adjust `maxfev=2000` and so on.. but it is not advisable